# SQL - speeding up performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have merged several css imports into one table - but this call takes about 70 seconds to complete. Is there a way of rewriting this to speed it up?

```
SELECT 
    `table_merged`.Property AS 'Property',
    AVG(`table_merged`.`Value`) AS 'Average Asking Price'
FROM
    `table_merged`
WHERE 
    `table_merged`.`Area` LIKE '%NW1%'
    AND `table_merged`.`Property` LIKE '%2-bed flat%'
    AND `table_merged`.`Year` = '2016'
GROUP BY 
    `table_merged`.Property, `table_merged`.`Year`
ORDER BY
    `table_merged`.Property ASC
```

Output is

```
| Property   | Average Asking Price
| 2-bed flat | 751427.1935581862
```

Comment: you're doing `%..%` "like" matches. those are inherently slow because they force a full-table scan.

Comment: The `LIKE`s really mess things up.  You might need to use full text indexes, although that might be tricky on the strings you are searching.

Comment: I've removed the LIKE on the 2-bed-flat -- but I didn't see an improvement in performance -- @GordonLinoff full text indexes on the NW1?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot that can be done with the query as it is. Your biggest performance hit right now is your use of `%...%` style `LIKE` statements. As Gordon has already mentioned in the comments, this basically removes MySQL's ability to use indexes.

The best solution here would be to slightly alter your schema. I would suggest creating a table that stores the type of property (like 2-bed flat) and then some kind of code (could just be an int). Searching on a code without the `LIKE` statement would give you the ability to use an index, and if you absolutely have to search on a like string, you can do it as a subselect on a much smaller table.

**Edit for further clarification:**

You're searching for any string of text that matches `%2-bed flat%`. My assumption is that you're doing this because you have strings like `cute 2-bed flat`, `2-bed flat near the water`, or other random marketing things. There is no way to optimize your `LIKE` STATEMENTS. They're slow, and that's an unfortunate fact of life.

I would add a column to your current tables. If the string matches the string `%2-bed flat%` then give it a value of something like `2bf`. While you're at it, you can do this with any other search strings you may use. Put an index on this column.

Once that's done, instead of using an intensive `LIKE` statement you can just do an indexed search on the new column.

Comment: -- what if I went back to the separate tables and tried to do a set of Joins?

Comment: The initial tables are in year batches -- but I need to run a query that does an average asking price on say 2013 and 2016

Comment: The problem isn't the join, the problem is how you're searching it. This style of `LIKE` statement is inherently slow.

Comment: -- So you are proposing -- taking the merged table -- copy it - dump ALL other property types and keep 2-bed-flat -- so in a way make a set of tables that are "property type" specific?

Comment: The smartest thing to do would be to do an update on the existing table so it has indexable indicators.

Comment: "indexable indicators" -- please elaborate - you mean set these coloumns as index's?

Comment: Ah your assumption is wrong -- I have changed that LIKE to an = -- "2-bed flat" will be just what it is -- its the postcode that really needs to remain a LIKE

Comment: -- What if I stripped out a LOT of unused coloumns? would this help -- or is it just the number of entries?

Comment: @TheOldCounty: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121773/discussion-between-jacobm001-and-the-old-county).

Comment: Well - if we can continue here -- if I drop unused coloumns would that make the difference?

Comment: @TheOldCounty: no